# what is the easiest way to integrate JSON binding in Jersey?

Tags: java, json, jersey

According to the documentation, MOXy is now the default way to integrate JSON binding in Jersey. However it's pretty painful to setup, require multiple external jars...

I've looked at using Jackson, but I have similar issues...

What is the easiest solution to provide JSON support in Jersey?

(a simple one small jar solution would be great!)

Comment: Why is including external jars painful? You should be using Maven or Gradle for your project.

Comment: I'm using GSON for that purpose, and still happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a JSON library with no compile dependencies, Google **GSON** might be the one.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
 <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
 <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It's a relatively small jar (227kb) and a well documented project : 
https://github.com/google/gson

Now to answer your title question, the easiest way might be to include **jersey-json** (based on jackson) because it will handle automatically the conversion of your response in JSON by simply adding a param to your servlet :

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

And adding annotations on your controller's methods :

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // to convert a bean to json
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // to convert json into your bean
```

Dependency for jersey-json below :

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
 <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
 <version>1.19.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

With maven , you can get json support (using moxy) with simply adding the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Please let me know if you want the full pom for related libraries